# How to recursively delete files filled with zeros?

Tags: delete

I have many files in a folder tree, of which some are filled with zeros and others are real files.

How can I delete files filled with zeros recursively?

Comment: what do you mean by "filled with zeroes"? Are they empty files with zero size, or something else?

Comment: I mean dummy files created when we start (something like) torrent download. The files display the final size but when we compress them they show their actual size. I want to separate real downloaded files from dummy files by deleting the dummy files.

Comment: Those files "filled with zeroes" are called "sparse files": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file. I didn't find any way to reliably detect them automatically, as a file may be only "partially" sparse. I think a better way to approach this problem is to have your bittorrent client keep incomplete files in a working directory and move them elsewhere once they are complete. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to identify sparse files by using the find command:

```
find -type f -printf "%S\t%p\n" 2>/dev/null | awk '{if ($1 < 1.0) print $1 $2}'
```

You can probably add some more find parameters to look for semi-sparse files, though those will probably depend more on your specific situation.

source: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8757/find-sparse-files